# Non-responsive HTML table when created with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my problem. It may be a little bit convoluted, so, please, bear with me.

I have a javascript function that reads data from the financial website and loads it into an HTML table (table id="transformTbl"). My table and header tags are created in HTML but tr's and td's for body of the table are created from javascript function using innerHTML. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
  {
    myData.innerHTML +=
    "<tr align='center'><td>" + earnings.reportedDate + "</td>" +
    "<td align='center'>" + earnings.reportedEPS + "</td>" +
    "<td align='right'>" + earnings.estimatedEPS + "</td>" +
    "<td align='right'>" + earnings.surprise + "</td></tr>";
  }
```

This logic is working perfectly. The data is displayed and all CSS styling applies to the table and to all its elements.

I have another javascript function that does the following. When I click on any row in that HTML table, the function takes the date cell from that row, manipulates it to create a "from" and "to" dates, and calls another financial API which returns a JSON file with a set of rows for that date range. I then parse that JSON file and display the data in a chart.

Here is the snippet of that function which deals with the click on the row:

```
  let tbl = document.getElementById('transformTbl');
  let earndays = document.getElementById('earndays');
  for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++)
    {
      tbl.rows[i].onclick = async function()
       {
         let earnDate = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
         olddate=new Date(earnDate.getFullYear(),earnDate.getMonth(),earnDate.getDate()-earndays);
         newdate=new Date(earnDate.getFullYear(),earnDate.getMonth(),earnDate.getDate()+earndays);
         let oldtime = olddate.getTime()/1000;
         let newtime = newdate.getTime()/1000;
                     e.t.c - rest of the code
```

This logic works on another one of my pages. On that page, all my rows are created in HTML and populated with PHP from MySQL database. They are not created from javascript. That's the only difference.

But here I am stuck because javascript does not recognize rows created by the function. It only sees one row, the header. When I click on the header, it fails, of course, because the header row doesn't have a legitimate date. But when I click on any other row, nothing happens. I displayed "tbl.rows.length" in console.log and it came back with 1, which means that getElementById returned the table with just one row.

I know that there is a different way of creating tables in javascript. If I don't find the solution to my problem I will try to do it differently. But at this point, my main focus is on functionality. I will re-work the logic later when I learn more about javascript.

Here is how my table is defined. I used innerHTML to add tr and td to tbody element (with id="myData):

```
  <h2 id = "h2header">Earnings History</h2>
      <table id="transformTbl">
        <thead id="myHeader"></thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Reported Date</th>
          <th>Reported EPS</th>
          <th>Estimated EPS</th>
          <th>Surprise</th>
         </tr>
        <tbody id="myData"><tbody>
      </table>
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Can you post the HTML structure for a page that you can't select the data from?  I am having trouble understanding the problem without more context. My gut feeling is that the HTML with the rows you want to affect is part of a different document node. You may need to use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` with the `+` selector (sibling) to select the correct node(s)

Comment: I added it to my original post. Thanks.

Comment: `I used innerHTML to add tr and td to tbody element (with id="myData):` are you perhaps adding the click handlers before the elements have been added to the table? You can select all the `tr` elements in the example you posted by doing `document.querySelectorAll('#transformTbl tr')`

Comment: I think that's most likely the answer. I need to play with it a little.